# Unknown command: --environment=Development during testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit

I created an ASP.NET project and wrote some integration tests for it. But when I tried to run `dotnet test` this shows up:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : Unknown command: --environment=Development


Test Run Aborted with error System.Exception: One or more errors occurred.
 ---> System.Exception: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---.
```

As I understand something tries to run dotnet executable with `--environment=Development` but this argument is invalid even though it is used in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

I tried creating new ASP.NET project (no controllers, services, database etc. just API that does nothing and an empty test) but I couldn't reproduce the error again.

Initially I created my project and solution in the same folder by accident and had to manually move project to subfolder. Everything worked fine after I did that so I assumed it's fine. Maybe that is the reason.

Here's how I access application during testing:

```cs
// TestingApplication.cs
public class TestingApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly Guid _appId = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Add mock/test services to the builder here
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvcCore().AddApplicationPart(typeof(Program).Assembly);
            services.AddScoped(sp => new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EfDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(
                    $"DATABASE CONNECTION STRING")
                .UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp)
                .Options);
        });
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var host = base.CreateHost(builder);

        using (var serviceScope = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EfDbContext>();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        return host;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        
        using (var serviceScope = Server.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EfDbContext>();
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }
    }
}

// BaseTest.cs
public class BaseTest : IDisposable, IClassFixture<TestingApplication>
{
    protected readonly TestingApplication Application;
    private HttpClient? _client;

    protected HttpClient Client => _client ??= Application.CreateClient();
    
    public BaseTest(TestingApplication testingApplication)
    {
        Application = testingApplication;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Application.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Some more info:

- Unit tests work just fine
- Initially I forgot to add `<InternalsVisibleTo Include="NameOfTestsProject" />` to the main project file, but it doesn't work either way.
- .NET 6, OS - Linux, IDE - Jetbrains Rider
- Rebuilding solution does not work
- Creating new project for unit tests doesn't help either

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**UPD** I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So this is just another example of  copy-pasting someone else's code without checking. I had copied something along the lines of:

```
if (args[0] == "something") {
 ...
} else if (args[0] == "something else") {
 ...
} else {
 // exit with code 1 here and print error
}
```

in my Program.cs. It worked fine by itself but when testing it caused this problem.